# Вывод в начало списка трёх случайных позиций из списка приоритетных

Tags: sql, mariadb

Есть таблица (используется MariaDB) со списком товаров. В таблице три поля:

| Имя поля | Описание |
| --- | --- |
| id | id товара |
| title | название товара |
| id_seller | id продавца |

В этой таблице для каждого  id_seller может быть много строк.
Есть список продавцов, товары которых всегда должны быть вверху списка.
Но - вверху списка должны быть только три случайно выбранных товара от трёх разных продавцов, а остальные товары сортируются в обычном порядке.

Как это реализовать в sql-запросе? Если использовать order by FIELD (id_seller, <список>), то вверху будут все товары всех продавцов из списка, а надо только чтобы три случайных товара трёх случайных продавцов из списка.

Comment: возможно, подобное лучше через union сделать.

Comment: *используется MariaDB* Вообще-то надо указывать точную версию.

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из собственного опыта предлагаю разделить задачу на 2 части.

1. Процедура вычисления поля сортировки.
2. Вывод запроса

Если надо вытащить топ позиций, то надо сделать еще одно поле в таблице товаров для сортировки например topOrderId.
В нем менеджер магазина или твоя процедура предварительно определяет позиции которые надо поднять наверх.

Дальше просто сортируешь по этому полю.

```
select * from Seller s 
inner join Products p on s.sallerid = p.sallerid
order by p.topOrderId desc
```

Менеджеры особенно любят вручную менять это поле, поскольку это дает им возможность гибко управлять продажами.

Если уже есть таблица с приоритетными позициями просто подключи сортировку по ней

```
select * from Seller s 
inner join Products p on s.sallerid = p.sallerid
left join ProductsTop pt on pt.productId = p.productId
order by pt.topOrderId desc
```

Comment: слова "случайный" вы в вопросе пропустили или проигнорировали?

Comment: случайность сортировки задается при работе процедуры по созданию сортировки или задается менеджером по продажам.

Comment: весь ваш ответ о том что надо отсортировать запрос по какому то полю, которое где-то взять. боюсь, это вряд ли хоть чем-то поможет автору вопроса.

Comment: вывод случайных позиций в реальных продажах практически не используется. В серьезных компаниях есть менеджер или даже целый отдел, который "случайно" выводит покупателям нужные позиции. Но если все таки вы решили пустить продажи на самотёк то хотя бы проверьте их наличие на складе.

Comment: да хоть общий отдел хоть не общий. от того, что из 200 товаров этих трех избранных поставщиков 10 товаров пометят кандидатами в случайные для запроса ничего не изменится. авто в любом случае хочет случайность, пусть в урезанной выборке и не полной номенклатуре